# Disabling Ads on a Kindle with Special Offers

Tags: kindle

If I get the Kindle with Special Offers can I upgrade to disable the ads? Would it cost more than just buying a Kindle without Special Offers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Amazon's [help on Special Offers](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200671290):

> ### Unsubscribe from Special Offers
>
> You can unsubscribe from Special Offers on your Kindle if you do not want to receive Sponsored Screensavers and Special Offers.
>
> Amazon is able to offer Kindle models at a subsidized price by delivering Special Offers and Sponsored Screensavers. **If you originally purchased a Kindle Special Offer Device you will be charged a one-time payment to unsubscribe from this service.**

Last I checked, the one-time payment that was listed for me was the same as the original amount I saved by buying a With-Special-Offers device.